# Is inheritance a special case of embedded struct in Go?

Tags: inheritance, struct, go

In Go, is `type Txt string` simply a shortcut for `type Txt struct {string}`?

Comment: No, the [underlying type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) of `Txt` is `string`. A struct is a composite type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers to all your questions is a loud "No!".

1. Embedding a `string` into a struct is basically a useless example of embedding as `string` has no methods which could get promoted to the embedding type.
2. The construct `type Txt string` defines a new type named Txt and the underlying type is a string. `Txt` has different method set as it is a different type. But as its underlying type is `string` you may freely type convert them.
3. `type T string` is not a shortcut for `type S struct { string }`, e.g. you cannot do
   `t := T{"foo"}`, only `t := T("foo")` works and for `S` it is the other way around.
4. Embedding has absolutely no relation to inheritance. These are two different things. Mimicking inheritance with embedding is doomed to fail as you cannot do inheritance in Go. (This is a general advice, it is a very useful advice; but some specific inheritance problems might be doable with embedding. Just forget about inheritance and you will be happier.)
5. Embedding is useful if two types have common data and methods in which case embedding provides some nice syntactic sugar: Instead of `type T struct { c common; r rest }; t := T{...}; t.common.method()` you can do `type T struct { common; r rest }; t := T{...}; t.method()` which saves typing but is basically the same code. Package testing contains nice examples.

Answer (score 4):

No

```
type Txt string
type StringStruct struct {
    string
}

func main() {
    var txt Txt = "abc"
    fmt.Println(len(txt))

    var str string = "abc"
    fmt.Println(len(str))

    // Uncomment me to get a compiler error!
    /* var ss StringStruct = StringStruct{"abc"}
    fmt.Println(len(ss)) */
}
```

You can't call `len` on the embedded one. You have to call `len(ss.string)`, thus it's safe to say that `type Txt string` is not shorthand for `type Txt struct{ string }`.

Answer (score 2):

No,`string` is a native type, like `int`, `uint`, `float`, etc.

Internally it's a slice of sorts.

Quoting http://blog.golang.org/strings

> In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes.
>
> It's important to state right up front that a string holds arbitrary
> bytes. It is not required to hold Unicode text, UTF-8 text, or any
> other predefined format. As far as the content of a string is
> concerned, it is exactly equivalent to a slice of bytes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point. I understand that I could use any of those native types in my example instead of string. The question could be written as: is inheritance a particular sort of embedded struct in Go?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and explain it better, also I'm not sure where in your question you mention inheritance or embedding.

Comment: You don't inherit types. Type declarations in Go can have underlying types, [but the new type is different from the underlying type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations). You can embed structs and interfaces, but this is a different concept and has nothing to do with types.